# Unable to Deploy War file on OpenShipt using git

Tags: openshift

Please help me how to deploy war on openshift app.I have put our war file in webapps folder and push code but my war is  not deployed.

[image]

[image]

after this default page will be open on app url.Please help me.

Comment: What url are you testing it at?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to deploy pre compiled java applications to your OpenShift gear, but you don't want to waste space by storing them in your git repository, then these directions are for you!

Create an application on OpenShift and select either the Tomcat 6 (JBoss EWS 1.0) or Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) cartridges.
Use the git clone command to download the source code for your application to your computer.
Remove the src directory and the pom.xml file from your application that you cloned to your computer.
DO NOT place your WAR files into the webapps directory.
Next, you need to do a git commit -am "some message here" to make sure that your changes are committed. Lastly, you need to do a git push to deploy your changes to your OpenShift gear.

Now comes the fun part, you need to use SCP or SFTP (with public key authentication of course) to upload your files to the correct location on your gear.
You need to place your WAR files into this folder: `app-root/dependencies/jbossews/webapps` on your gear.

If you run `rhc tail $appname`, shortly after the transfer is done you will see entries appear in the logs showing that your WAR file has been deployed and at what context.

The WAR files that you add into the webapps directory will be deployed at a context that matches the name of the WAR file.
For Example:
If you add a file called mywebsite.war, it will be available at app-domain.rhcloud.com/mywebsite. If there is an application that you would like to be available at app-domain.rhcloud.com/ (also known as the root context) then you should name that file ROOT.war.

If you need to replace them, just upload a new copy, or if you want to remove them, just ssh into your server and delete the file you uploaded and it will be un-deployed.